# Is there a way to switch environments while using Jint.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, jint

I'm currently using the [Jint.NET](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) JavaScript console engine for C#, and I'm attempting to emulate separate JavaScript environments that the user can switch between.

However, I don't want to create an entirely new console engine for each JavaScript environment and cause a large overhead, instead just switch between them using a single engine and store the environments somewhere else, eg:

```
   engine 1
   |      |
   |      |
env 1   env 2
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Perhaps: Could swap in/out global’s properties AND run user code inside an (anonymous) function to avoid global-scope pollution. Not full isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this, although there's no documentation for this anywhere that I can find, so this may be an unintended method. You need to use `EnterExecutionContext` on newly created `LexicalEnvironments`, and you can switch between them to have separate JS environments.

Here's an example:

```
using Jint.Runtime.Environments;
using Jint.Native.Object;
using Jint.Native.Global;

//Create a new object instance and environment.
JSObjectInstance = GlobalObject.CreateGlobalObject(jintEngine);
JSEnvironment = LexicalEnvironment.NewObjectEnvironment(jintEngine, JSObjectInstance, jintEngine.GlobalEnvironment, false);

//Enter the new environment.
jintEngine.EnterExecutionContext(JSEnvironment, JSEnvironment, new Jint.Native.JsValue(false));
```

And when you're done with that environment, you can leave using `LeaveExecutionContext`, and rejoin the default global one like so:

```
jintEngine.EnterExecutionContext(jintEngine.GlobalEnvironment, jintEngine.GlobalEnvironment, jintEngine.Global);
```